# How can I invoke a default subcommand with cobra?

Tags: go, go-cobra

Using cobra, if my app is invoked without a specific action (but arguments), I'd like to run a default command:

```
// rootCmd represents the base command when called without any subcommands
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "mbmd",
    Short: "ModBus Measurement Daemon",
    Long:  "Easily read and distribute data from ModBus meters and grid inverters",

    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        run(cmd, args)
    },
}
```

However, since the root command doesn't have all arguments the child command has this fails as it's apparently now aware of the child command's arguments:

```
❯ go run main.go -d sma:126@localhost:5061 --api 127.1:8081 -v
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d
```

as opposed to:

```
❯ go run main.go run -d sma:126@localhost:5061 --api 127.1:8081 -v
2019/07/29 20:58:10 mbmd unknown version (unknown commit)
```

How can I programmatically instantiate/invoke a child command?

Comment: By calling `run()`. Every command in Cobra just calls a function. You can call the same function from multiple cobra commands.

Comment: As I've done? That only honors the root command arguments, but not the run command's arguments :/

Comment: You have now (Oct. 2021) have two possible workarounds. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66795805/6309).

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution:

```golang
    cmd, _, err := rootCmd.Find(os.Args[1:])
    // default cmd if no cmd is given
    if err == nil && cmd.Use == rootCmd.Use && cmd.Flags().Parse(os.Args[1:]) != pflag.ErrHelp {
        args := append([]string{defaultCmd.Use}, os.Args[1:]...)
        rootCmd.SetArgs(args)
    }

    if err := rootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

Replace `defaultCmd` with one you want to be default

This part `cmd.Flags().Parse(os.Args[1:]) != pflag.ErrHelp` keeps help command working for root command if no arguments was set

Answer (score 2):

March 2021: You might consider a workaround as the one presented in [`spf13/cobra` issue 823](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/823#issuecomment-617863653)

```golang
func subCommands() (commandNames []string) {
    for _, command := range cmd.Commands() {
        commandNames = append(commandNames, append(command.Aliases, command.Name())...)
    }
    return
}

func setDefaultCommandIfNonePresent() {
    if len(os.Args) > 1 { 
        potentialCommand := os.Args[1]
        for _, command := range subCommands() {
            if command == potentialCommand {
                return
            }
        }
        os.Args = append([]string{os.Args[0], "<default subcommand>"}, os.Args[1:]...)
    }

}

func main() {
    setDefaultCommandIfNonePresent()
    if err := cmd.Execute(); err != nil {
        zap.S().Error(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

> The difference here is that it checks if `len(os.Args) > 1` before changing the default subcommand.
>
> This means that, if ran without any arguments, it will print the default help command (with all of the subcommands).
> Otherwise, if supplied any arguments, it will use the subcommand.
>
> So, it will display the main '`help`' without arguments, and the subcommand's help if supplied '`-h`'/'`--help`'.

---

Or (Oct. 2021), from the [author](https://github.com/rmasci) of [PR 823](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/823#issuecomment-949732548):

> Latest solve for this is the following:
>
> #### `main.go`

```golang
func main() {
  // Define the default sub command 'defCmd' here. If user doesn't submit
  // using a default command, we'll use what is here.
  defCmd:="mydefaultcmd"
  cmd.Execute(defCmd)
}
```

#### `root.go`

```golang
func Execute(defCmd string) {
  var cmdFound bool
  cmd :=rootCmd.Commands()

  for _,a:=range cmd{
    for _,b:=range os.Args[1:] {
      if a.Name()==b {
       cmdFound=true
        break
      }
    }
  }
  if !cmdFound {
    args:=append([]string{defCmd}, os.Args[1:]...)
    rootCmd.SetArgs(args)
  }
  if err := rootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this solution and am using it in my new golang project [GitSpaces](https://github.com/davfive/gitspaces) that is going live this Spring.

To avoid having to check for the number of args, the most cobra-esque way to parse the command is to do it exactly the way that [`cobra:command.go:ExecuteC()`](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/bd914e58d69d65e494b45bdb40e90ca816b92fcc/command.go#L1089) does:

**root.go**

```
//... define rootCmd as &cobra.Command up here

func flagsContain(flags []string, contains ...string) bool {
    for _, flag := range contains {
        if slices.Contains(flags, flag) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func setDefaultCommandIfNonePresent(defaultCommand string) {
    // Taken from cobra source code in command.go::ExecuteC()
    var cmd *cobra.Command
    var err error
    var flags []string
    if rootCmd.TraverseChildren {
        cmd, flags, err = rootCmd.Traverse(os.Args[1:])
    } else {
        cmd, flags, err = rootCmd.Find(os.Args[1:])
    }

    // If no command was on the CLI, then cmd will return with
    // the value of rootCmd.Use (which would run the help output
    // in the full Execute() command)
    if err != nil || cmd.Use == rootCmd.Use {
        if !flagsContain(flags, "-v", "-h", "--version", "--help") {
            rootCmd.SetArgs(append(os.Args[1:], defaultCommand))
        }
    }
}

// let main package set default command ...
func ExecuteWithDefaultCommand(defaultCommand string) {
  if defaultCommand != "" {
     setDefaultCommandIfNonePresent(defaultCommand)
  }
  if err := rootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
}

// ... or handle the default command internally
func Execute() {
  setDefaultCommandIfNonePresent("default")
  if err := rootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
}
```